# OpenFileDialog store files permanently

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listbox

Is it possible to store the files that you have opened using OpenFileDialog in WPF? Currently, I have this code that opens a file from the computer and shows the directory of it in a listBox:

```
private void UploadEmployeeRank1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
        openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            foreach (string filename in openFileDialog.FileNames)
                employeeRank1PrivateMaterialsListBox.Items.Add(filename);
        }
    }
```

However, once I close the application and open in again, the file that I have loaded in the listBox is gone. How do I make it stay?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/

Comment: Store the location of the file in some fashion (e.g. application settings, json file, whatever) and read it into memory when you load your application.

Comment: Is it possible to store it in an SQL table?

Comment: If you wanted to, yes. The filename that `OpenFileDialog` returns is simply a string which is a path to the file - you can store it wherever or however you want.

Answer (score 0):

`OpenFileDialog` does not actually load the files. It returns you the path of the selected files. So at the end you will just need to save those strings.
One simple and quick way is to write them in local file.

Here are two functions that will save and load file paths in a file.

```
private void SaveFiles()
{
    if (listBox1.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        StringBuilder files = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var file in listBox1.Items)
        {
            files.AppendLine(file.ToString());
        }

        File.WriteAllText("myfiles.txt", files.ToString());
    }
}

private void LoadFiles()
{
    if (File.Exists("myfiles.txt"))
    {
        string[] files = File.ReadAllLines("myfiles.txt");
        listBox1.Items.AddRange(files);
    }
}
```

`SaveFiles()` function loads the files from your listbox and saves each path as a new line in text file.
`LoadFiles()` function parses the file and loads the data in your listbox.